# is there a system that will redistribute a WiFi signal

Tags: authentication, wireless-networking, browser

Where I live we have community WiFi and it is authenticated with a password
via a browser. This all works just fine on my Android/iPhone devices but I have a Blu-Ray device and a couple of Nintendo devices where this won't work.

I was wondering if there was a router or some other hub that would trap this WiFi and redistribute it. Or maybe login with my PC and then access the of for the WiFi signal?

Comment: Like a wifi signal booster? Standalone device, costs about as much as a "decent" router?

Answer (score 2):

the simplest solution ist to get two cheap wifi routers.

the first has to be configured in client mode - that means it connects to the community wifi as if it was a computer/smartphone/whatever. If it is configured correctly you can plug your computer in via a ethernet and you will be assigned an ip address and redirected to the captive portal as if you where connected via wifi (you will have to turn your laptops wifi off for this test)

next part is to get your own network - so you take the second router and connect the cable you just plugged into your laptop into the second routers wan. the second router should work fine using factory defaults (just make sure you are using secure wifi credentials).

now when you connect to your own wifi or the lan ports of the second router you will be prompted to login on the captive portal as usual but this login will be used for everyone connected to your new private network.

of course it is also possible doing this with just one router but as this stuff got damn cheap by now it is not even worth the hassle. you can take one better router for the private network if you want to have fast transfer between your devices and some simple box for the connection to the community wifi.

I recommend this setup anyway since it provides you with an private network which is not accessable from the other devices in the community network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to spoof the devices MAC address with a computer running Linux or Mac OS X so that you can consent to the captive portal with your web browser. (A Live CD will do if you are not already using one of these operating systems.) Then, you can reconnect the device for as long as the provider caches the record.